# How to handle incremental fetches from Salesfore and Database Component

Tags: salesforce, mule

I have a salesforce query which returns contact information.  I need to save the data in 2 tables. In the first table I have to store some metadata about the contacts in an intermediate state. I then get the auto-generated metadata table ID from the metadata saved and apply it to every contact. I then have to save the contact data into a database table and then finally update the contacts metadata to its final state. The problem is that there is a lot of data so I have to include a fetch size when performing this process. What I want to achieve should be something like this, please note this is only what I am looking to achieve. How can I know that the fetch contacts is complete, so that I can save the final state? How can I structure the flow for transactions?
Ideally, I would like to pass the ConsumerIterator to a Java component where I can easily control the process. Can I pass a reference of the ConsumerIterator to a Java component for example? If I can how can I do so?

```
<sfdc:query fetchSize="100" config-ref="sfdc-connector" 

query="dsql:SELECT   Id, Account.Id,

  Account.Name, Account.PersonEmail, Account.LastName  From Contact" />

 dw:transform-message metadata:id="d1f6ab4f-4b40-4e30-ae" doc:name="trnsfm">

 <enricher target="variable:metaInfo"> 
   <flow-refname="getContactMetadata"/>
 </enricher> 

  <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0

.//Rest of transformer

<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Save Metatdata">
  ...

 </db:insert>

<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Save contacts">
....
<db:insert>

 <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Update Metadata   
      Final State">
 ....
 <db:insert>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.  I wrote a Java Component, implementing Callable and grabbed the ConsumerIterator. I then was able to use the iterator to obtain items in fetchSize. I then used Spring Jdbc since the data model is simple enough to transactionally save the data